# using _.each in backbone template

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js

I am trying to use a backbone foreach statement in a template and it is giving me an error below.

**SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

I am trying to pass an object like this to it...

```
var multiSortDiv = _.template($('#multiSortContainerTemp').html(), { "cols": aoCols });
```

Here is my template :

```
<script type="text/template" id="multiSortContainerTemp">
<div id="multiSortContainer">
    <br>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;width:400px;color:Blue">Multi-Sort - Check columns to Sort By</p>
    <br>
     <% _.each(%><%= cols %><%, function(val, i) { %>
       <label style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:7px"><%= val.sTitle %></label>
       <input id="multiSort_" + <%= i %> type="checkbox" style="margin-left:2px" />
     <%}) %>
</div>
</script>
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here in the template???

Comment: `id="multiSort_" + <%= i %>` you are using `+` within html code

Comment: Ok I changed it to this <input id="multiSort_<%= i %>" type="checkbox" style="margin-left:2px" /> and it still gives same error

Comment: Ok I fixed it. Here is correct template code : <div id="multiSortContainer">
    <br>
    <p style="font-weight:bold;width:400px;color:Blue">Multi-Sort - Check columns to Sort By</p>
    <br>
    <% _.each(<%= cols %>, function(val, i) { %>
        <label style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:7px"><%= cols[i].sTitle %></label>
        <input id="multiSort_<%= i %>" type="checkbox" style="margin-left:2px" />
    <%}); %>
</div>

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your template in this place: `<% _.each(cols, function(val, i) { %>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct template :

```
<div id="multiSortContainer">
   <br>
   <p style="font-weight:bold;width:400px;color:Blue">Multi-Sort - Check columns to Sort By</p>
   <br>
    <% _.each(<%= cols %>, function(val, i) { %>
       <label style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:7px"><%= cols[i].sTitle %></label>
       <input id="multiSort_<%= i %>" type="checkbox" style="margin-left:2px" />
    <%}); %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it. Here is correct template code:

```
<div id="multiSortContainer"> 
  <p style="font-weight:bold;width:400px;color:Blue">Multi-Sort - Check columns to Sort By</p>
  <% _.each(<%= cols %>, function(val, i) { %> 
    <label style="font-weight:bold;margin-left:7px">
    <%= cols[i].sTitle %></label> 
    <input id="multiSort_<%= i %>" type="checkbox" style="margin-left:2px" />
  <%}); %> 
</div>
```